# Chinese painting signature and seal translation (Characters identified: 羅鼎華印)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal, calligraphy

I have a Chinese watercolour and the scene is two birds with flowers. I cannot interpret the signature nor the seal and really need some help on this. [image]

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing here but the artist name, which is 羅鼎華 (Mandarin: Luó Dǐnghuá).

The calligraphy says

> 鼎華
>
> Dǐnghuá

The seal says

> 羅鼎蕐（華）印
>
> Seal of Luó Dǐnghuá

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply 